# How do I create custom rollup types in icCube?

Tags: mdx, olap, measure, iccube

How do I create custom rollup types in icCube?

Say, I need WAvg (which is already implemplemented there) instead of plain Avg function. But I it is not on the dropdown list in measure creation form. What should I do now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alexander, I assume you're talking about the cube builder.

The [weighted-average](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Wavg.html) is not available in the list of available aggregation types because there's no straitforward way to implement it at cube level. Aggregation types available for standard measures are simple calculations. Those calculation are meant to be very fast for millions of rows. You've two kinds of average available for standard measures : 'average on leafs(rows)' and 'average on children', which might be near what you're looking for.

In the case of a weighted average you have to create a calculated measure: you need to defined the values to "weight" your underlying measure against. The documentation [weighted-average](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Wavg.html) is giving several examples.